# Java(generated) folder in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, generated, android-studio-4.0

What is the java(generated) folder in the project structure of the Android Studio? How does it differ from the java folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some libraries, like Dagger, Room, Navigation components, that provide you convinient possibilities to write a code, but under hood they are generating java classes, which are used. that java classes are generated in that folder with the same package as original classes, f. e. you have `UserDao` interface in your code to store user info to sqlite db, for it's usage Room generates `UserDao_Impl` class which is used afterwards.